# disable Subversion upgrade alert xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

Each time I open a new project xcode 5 throws an alert to upgrade to subversion 1.7. Is there any way to disable this alert.

I am aware that If I check don't warn me again for this workspace will stop showing alert. But I am looking for a solution so That I don;t have to keep doing for each workspace.

Thanks